# Disable editing in Radgrid from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am new to telerik components. I have a page that contains a Radgrid, and I want to disable editing in radgrid from code behind.  I have disabled everything I thought would affect editing, but it still has edit on row-double click. How can I disable that?

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid_ElateTarkeKar" runat="server" CssClass="RadGrid" GridLines="None"
                                AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                ShowStatusBar="True" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AllowAutomaticInserts="True" ClientSettings-Selecting-AllowRowSelect="true"
                                AllowAutomaticUpdates="True" DataSourceID="SqldtsElateTarkeKar" CellSpacing="0" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" 
                                OnInsertCommand="RadGrid_ElateTarkeKar_InsertCommand"  OnItemCommand="RadGrid_ElateTarkeKar_ItemCommand" 
                                OnItemDeleted="RadGrid_ElateTarkeKar_ItemDeleted" OnItemInserted="RadGrid_ElateTarkeKar_ItemInserted" 
                                OnItemUpdated="RadGrid_ElateTarkeKar_ItemUpdated" OnUpdateCommand="RadGrid_ElateTarkeKar_UpdateCommand" Width="100%" Height="250px" Skin="Hay">

                                <ExportSettings ExportOnlyData="true" IgnorePaging="true" OpenInNewWindow="true">
                                    <Excel Format="ExcelML"></Excel>
                                    <Excel AutoFitImages="true" />
                                    <Pdf FontType="Embed" AllowPrinting="true" />
                                    <Pdf DefaultFontFamily="Arial Unicode MS" />
                                </ExportSettings>

                                <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom" DataKeyNames="ElateTarkeKar_ID" EditMode="PopUp" Dir="RTL" AllowFilteringByColumn="true" NoDetailRecordsText="هیچ رکوردی وجود ندارد !" NoMasterRecordsText="هیچ رکوردی وجود ندارد !" DataSourceID="SqldtsElateTarkeKar">
                                    <CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF" AddNewRecordText="ایجاد رکورد جدید" RefreshText="بروزرسانی" ShowExportToExcelButton="true" ShowExportToWordButton="true" ShowExportToPdfButton="false"></CommandItemSettings>

                                    <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column" FilterControlWidth="20%"></RowIndicatorColumn>

                                    <ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column" FilterControlWidth="20%"></ExpandCollapseColumn>
                                    <Columns>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="ElateTarkeKar_ID" HeaderText="کد علت ترک کار" DataField="ElateTarkeKar_ID" FilterControlAltText="Filter ElateTarkeKar_ID column" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ElateTarkeKar_ID">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="ElateTarkeKar_Desc" HeaderText="علت ترک کار" DataField="ElateTarkeKar_Desc" FilterControlAltText="Filter ElateTarkeKar_Desc column" SortExpression="ElateTarkeKar_Desc">
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                      <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" ButtonType="ImageButton" Text="حذف" UniqueName="columnDelete" ConfirmText="آیا می خواهید رکورد مورد نظر را حذف کنید ؟" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow" ImageUrl="../../assets/img/icon/del-layer.png" ConfirmDialogHeight="180" ConfirmDialogWidth="380" FooterStyle-Width="60px" HeaderStyle-Width="60px" ItemStyle-Width="60px">
                                        </telerik:GridButtonColumn>

                                        <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Edit"  AndCurrentFilterFunction="Contains" ButtonType="ImageButton" ImageUrl="../../assets/img/icon/edit.png" AutoPostBackOnFilter="True" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" Text="ویرایش" FooterStyle-Width="60px" HeaderStyle-Width="60px" ItemStyle-Width="60px" UniqueName="columnEdit">
                                        </telerik:GridButtonColumn>

                                    </Columns>
                                    <EditFormSettings  InsertCaption="ایجاد علت ترک کار جدید" CaptionFormatString="ویرایش علت ترک کار با کد : {0}"
                                        CaptionDataField="ElateTarkeKar_ID" EditFormType="Template" PopUpSettings-Modal="true" FormTableStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FormCaptionStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" PopUpSettings-CloseButtonToolTip="بستن" UserControlName="popupform" PopUpSettings-Width="500">
                                        <EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1" FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn1 column"></EditColumn>

                                        <FormTableStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></FormTableStyle>

                                        <FormCaptionStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></FormCaptionStyle>
                                        <FormTemplate >
                                            <br/>
                                            <div class="portlet-body form form-horizontal">
                                                <div id="Div1" class="control-group" runat="server" visible="false">
                                                    <label class="control-label">
                                                        کد علت ترک کار :
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="controls">
                                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtElateTarkeKar_ID" Text='<%# Bind( "ElateTarkeKar_ID") %>' runat="server"> 
                                                        </asp:TextBox>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                                    <div class="span11">
                                                        <div class="control-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label">علت ترک کار  :</label>
                                                            <div class="controls">
                                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtElateTarkeKar_Desc" Text='<%# Bind("ElateTarkeKar_Desc")%>' CssClass="span10 tooltips pulsate-regular" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Font-Size="Large" ControlToValidate="txtElateTarkeKar_Desc"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                                    <div class="span6">
                                                        <div class="control-group">
                                                            <label class="control-label">

                                                            </label>
                                                            <div class="controls">

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="ipopup-actions">
                                                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn green" runat="server" ID="Button3" CommandName='<%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "PerformInsert" : "Update" %>'>
                                                        <i class="icon-ok"></i>
                                                            <%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "درج" : "ویرایش" %>
                                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn grey" runat="server" ID="Button4" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel">
                                                    <i class="icon-remove"></i> انصراف
                                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </FormTemplate>
                                        <PopUpSettings Modal="True" Width="500px" CloseButtonToolTip="بستن"></PopUpSettings>
                                    </EditFormSettings>
                                    <PagerStyle PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" />
                                </MasterTableView>
                                <ClientSettings ClientEvents-OnKeyPress="keyPress">
                                    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
                                    <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick" />
                                    <ClientEvents OnPopUpShowing="PopUpShowing" />
                                </ClientSettings>
                                <FilterItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                                <PagerStyle PageSizeControlType="RadComboBox" />
                                <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False">
                                </FilterMenu>
                            </telerik:RadGrid>
                            `
```

**Answer:**

Editing is available on row double click in some cases, so I used below code to disable this feature and then I hid edit button:

```
 radGrid.MasterTableView.EditMode = GridEditMode.InPlace;
 radGrid.ClientSettings.ClientEvents.OnRowDblClick = "";
 radGrid.MasterTableView.GetColumn("columnEdit").Display = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need to disable the edit/delete programmatically, this snippet should do the job:

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
if (yourCondition) 
  { 
    foreach( GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items ) 
    { 
        LinkButton btnDelete = (LinkButton)item.FindControl("columnDelete"); 
        btnDelete.Enabled = false; 

        LinkButton btnEdit = (LinkButton)item.FindControl("columnEdit"); 
        btnEdit.Enabled = false; 
    } 
  } 
}
```